# Dynamically changing the shown form on tree selection

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm currently learning the adf framework, and while doing this I found myself in a situation I am not able to solve.

I have a tree component that works fine. I also have different forms, corresponding to different levels of the tree. Rather than having all of the forms visible at one time, I would like to only show the one that corresponds to the selected item in the tree.

To solve this, I created af:switcher, created facets and moved the forms there. Here is where I am lost, how do I tell the switcher to change the form? I tried to link them together using the facetName on the switcher, but no success. I suspect I did not link the right thing there, but I could not find anything helpful from the tree either! I assume it has something to do with the selectionListener and a bean, but I could not figure out a way to do this. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Sample #50 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/index-101235.html#CodeCornerSamples

Frank

Comment: I had followed your example through, a minor typo was the problem. Damn copypasting from a pdf :)